# How to activate the dashboard

Tags: admin, dashboard

Brand new to wordpress, and I'm trying to install a portfolio template called Semplice, how do I activate or find the wordpress dashboard to activate Semplice as a theme, and use all of its functions?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your domain and type /wp-admin and log on with your username and password.

```
http//www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin
```

Then go to appearance, themes and then activate your theme. If it's not already installed you can either drag your theme to the wp-content/themes folder or install it from within the themes area.